# Not Seeing Nested Class as Exception

Tags: python-3.x, inner-classes

The following code says it cannot find MyError:

```
   class Test:
       class MyError(ValueError):
           pass

       def bad(self):
           raise MyError

       def myfunc(self):
           try:
               self.bad()
           except MyError as me:
               print(me)


   tt = Test()
   tt.myfunc()
```

When I run it I get this:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "testcase.py", line 16, in <module>
     tt.myfunc()
   File "testcase.py", line 11, in myfunc
     except MyError as me:
 NameError: name 'MyError' is not defined
```

What am I missing about referencing nested classes?

Comment: Classes are first-class in Python, and seeing as `MyError` is an attribute of the class, there needs to be an object that binds to that attribute. But it can also behave statically and be called in an unbound way just by prepending the `Test` class name first `Test.MyError`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I need to fully qualify the path to the class as `Test.MyError`

```
 class Test:
     class MyError(ValueError):
         pass

     def bad(self):
         raise Test.MyError

     def myfunc(self):
         try:
             self.bad()
         except Test.MyError as me:
             print(me)


 tt = Test()
 tt.myfunc()
```